# Hive: Reduce millisecond precision in timestamp

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, precision

In Hive, is there anyway to reduce millisecond precision (**not rounding**)?

For example I have the following timestamp with millisecond in 3 decimal places

```
2019-10-08 21:21:39.163
```

I want to get a timestamp exactly in 1 decimal place (remove two last milliseconds 63):

```
2019-10-08 21:21:39.1
```

I only get so far as to turning the timestamp into a decimal with one value precision:

```
cast(floor(cast(2019-10-08 21:21:39.163 AS double)/0.100)*0.100 AS decimal(16,1)) AS updatetime
```

This gives:

```
1570537299.1
```

**The problem:** I do not know how to turn the above value back to a timestamp in millisecond. Even better, if there is a better way to reduce timestamp precision from 3 to 1 decimal place, I will appreciate it.

The reason I have to cast the above code into decimal is because if I only do:

```
floor(cast(2019-10-08 21:21:39.163 AS double)/0.100)*0.100 AS exec_time
```

This gives something like:

```
1570537299.100000001
```

This is not good, since I need to join this table X with another table Y. 
Table X has timestamp like `2019-10-08 21:21:39.163`. 
But table Y stores data in each 100ms interval, whose timestamp is exactly: `2019-10-08 21:21:39.1`
The trailing 00000001 would prevent the timestamp from Table X to map exactly with Table Y

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove last two milliseconds, use `substr()` and cast to timestamp again if necessary. For example:

```
with your_data as
(
select timestamp('2019-10-08 21:21:39.163') as original_timestamp --your example
)

select original_timestamp, 
       substr(original_timestamp,1,21)            truncated_string,
       timestamp(substr(original_timestamp,1,21)) truncated_timestamp --this may be not necessary, timestamp is compatible w string
from your_data
```

Returns:

```
original_timestamp      truncated_string        truncated_timestamp
2019-10-08 21:21:39.163 2019-10-08 21:21:39.1   2019-10-08 21:21:39.1
```